# More than one JDBC Connectors one single topic

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have requirement to consume two exactly same table on different database (location also differ) to publish on same topic. 
Kafka JDBC connectors doesn't explain how it manage high-watermark so thought to check whats best practices in this scenario?
1. Can we keep 2 separate JDBC connector publishing to separate topic
2. Can we keep 2 separate JDBC connector publishing to same topic.

If we choose option 2 how Kafka JDBC connector manage in case message arrived into table concurrently at same time? How it manage different database time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Can we keep 2 separate JDBC connector publishing to separate topic

Yes.

> 2. Can we keep 2 separate JDBC connector publishing to same topic.

Yes

> how Kafka JDBC connector manage in case message arrived into table concurrently at same time?

You'll get both messages on the target topic. Your consumer would need logic in it to deal with the duplication if there is any. You could use a Single Message Transform to set the key on the message written to the topic and use that as part of the de-duplication.